# Attempting an INSERT INTO query with a form and php but database is not updating the record

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, foreign-keys

I have an activity table which i want the users to be able to add data to it from my website. I have a Form and an INSERT INTO Query but when i click submit button the form clears but the database does not have the inputted record. I think the issue is that one of the fields (activity_cat) is a FOREIGN KEY on the table I'm trying to insert to.

```
<form>

<form action="" method="post">
Activity Category: <input type="text" name="activity_cat" /><br><br>
Activity Name: <input type="text" name="activity_name" /><br><br>
Activity Address: <textarea name="activity_address"> </textarea><br><br>
Activity Description: <textarea name="activity_description"> </textarea><br><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

The above form is my html form and the below is my php code to insert into the database

```
<?php


$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
die(mysqli_error());
}


if(isset($_POST["submit"])){


$sql = "INSERT INTO `activity`(`activity_cat`, `activity_name`, `activity_address`, `activity_description`)
VALUES ('".$_POST["activity_cat"]."','".$_POST["activity_name"]."','".$_POST["activity_address"]."','".$_POST["activity_description"]."')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New Record Inserted Successfully');</script>";
} else {
echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error."');</script>";
}


}


?>
```

The "activity_cat" is a Foreign Key in the "activity" table. This is so the activities are categorised into different categories. Im not sure if this is the problem or not. I am entering the exact activity_cat records that are in categories table but still no luck. Ideally i would like a drop down menu which the user can select the category type for the option in the form. Any help with this would be appreciated. I am new to coding, especially PHP and mysql. Any other information needed please ask

Thank You

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection attacks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Do not take this code live.  It'll be hacked in seconds

Comment: it is not going to be live. This is for project and learning purposes only

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a name attribute on your submit button. 
Add name='submit' 
On your submit button

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that your code is prone to SQL Injection attacks, you are checking if `submit` is set, when you did not provide a name for your button.

Add a name attribute to your input tag like so:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I have added a name attribute to the input type but still no luck

Comment: No errors. When submit is clicked the page reloads with an empty form as if it has been submitted. However when i check the database the records has not been inserted into the table.

Comment: Can you update your question with the recent change?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an un-closed form tag:

```
<form> <!-- What is this -->

<form action="" method="post">
```

Second, (and this is what's causing the problem in this case):

You did not specify an action to your form! The `action` attribute must be set to the path of the php file which holds your script, which inserts stuff into your database.

For example:

`something.html`:

```
<form action="inserter.php" method="post">
  Activity Category: <input type="text" name="activity_cat" /><br><br>
  Activity Name: <input type="text" name="activity_name" /><br><br>
  Activity Address: <textarea name="activity_address"> </textarea><br><br>
  Activity Description: <textarea name="activity_description"> </textarea><br><br>

  <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

`inserter.php:`

```
<?php

    $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass, $db_name);
    if (!$conn) {
        die(mysqli_error());
    }

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){    
        //You don't need to concatenate, you can just put the variables directly into a string (which are double quoted) like this: ${variable's_identifier}
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `activity`(`activity_cat`, `activity_name`, `activity_address`, `activity_description`)
          VALUES ('${_POST["activity_cat"]}','${_POST["activity_name"]}','${_POST["activity_address"]}','${_POST["activity_description"]}')";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New Record Inserted Successfully');</script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error."');</script>";
        }
    }

    //You SHOULD close the connection when you are done!
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

**However, please do use parameterized prepared statements!**

```
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass, $db_name);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `activity`(`activity_cat`, `activity_name`, `activity_address`, `activity_description`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $_POST["activity_cat"], $_POST["activity_name"], $_POST["activity_address"], $_POST["activity_description"])
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

$conn->close();
```